# R: constructing a data frame with many columns using paste()

Tags: r

```
col1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
col2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
col3 <- c(7, 8, 9)
```

- On the one hand `data.frame(col1, col2, col3)`

gives

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    4    7
2    2    5    8
3    3    6    9
```

- On the other hand `paste0("col", 1:3, collapse=", ")`

gives

```
[1] "col1, col2, col3"
```

- **Question:** Is it possible to construct the data frame using something like `data.frame(paste0("col", 1:3, collapse=", "))`?

Comment: If you have a string as shown in the example, `str1 <- paste0("col", 1:3, collapse=", ");
data.frame(mget(strsplit(str1, ', ')[[1]]))`

Comment: @akrun: what is str1?

Comment: It is the string.  I guess I understand your question correctly.  Do you need to construct a data.frame from a string as showed in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we already have a string that have the objects pasted together, we can use `strsplit` to split the string and get the values with `mget`.  This will return a `list` output.  Then wrap it with `data.frame` to convert it to 'data.frame`

```
data.frame(mget(strsplit(str1, ', ')[[1]]))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- paste0("col", 1:3, collapse=", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `mget`

```
do.call(cbind, mget(paste0("col", 1:3)))
```

Where the `paste0` generates the variable names, `mget` gets the associated values, and `cbind` puts them together into a data frame.